# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question has been asked probably too many times before but none of those solutions has been able to help me out.I keep getting the above error even if I have everything in place AFAIK.

I have included the button in the html code but when i try to find them through jquery error: "Cannot read property 'ready' of null" occurs moreover it does not even recognize the document.ready function. Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jsencrypt.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jsencrypt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="System.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="System.IO.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="System.BigInt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="System.BitConverter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Convert.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Security.Cryptography.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Text.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("button");

        });
      //  debugger;
     //   var element = document.getElementById("btntest");

        //$("#btntest").click(function () {
        //    alert("button");
        //});

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btntest" value="Test" />


    <span>Name:</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Send" />




</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions to resolve this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Aside from your issue, why did you include `"Scripts/jsencrypt.min.js"` and `"Scripts/jsencrypt.js"` twice?

Comment: @ Tao P. R.: I have removed those now..not using them anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a CDN for example -
 https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

I don't see any problem with the code as long as $ has been overwritten by any other reference below it. If the code does not work with CDN reference, you can also try adding the jquery reference at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It was my bad.Changing the order of the jquery files did the trick. Added the reference of jquery and jquery.min files at the bottom of the other .js files. Might help some one as well.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="System.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="System.IO.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="System.BigInt.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="System.BitConverter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Convert.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Security.Cryptography.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="System.Text.js"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/jquery.js">
```